# How to make a div fill up remaining horizontal space

Tags: html, css

I have two divs.  One that is floated left and one floated right.  The one of the left has a width set to 18% and a min-width of 217px.  I want to have the div on the right take up the remaining space, while also being able to resize to fit the window.

The problem I am having is that I can set the right div's width to 82% and to float right, which works until I make the window side too small, in which case the min-width of the left div kicks in and it stops shrinking.  The right div doesn't have enough space to fit, so it is pushed down.

Here's some sample code.

**HTML**

```
    <div id="div1">
       stuff inside of it
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
       stuff inside of it
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #div1
    {
     float: left;
     width: 18%;
     height: 100vh;
     min-width: 130px;
     box-shadow: 0px .3em .2em #000;
     z-index: 2;
    }

    #div2
    {
     width: 82%;
     float: right;
     z-index: 1;
    }
```

So this is where I'm stuck, how should I approach fixing div2?  I've tried using a table instead of divs, but a border appeared around the cells that I couldn't change and it removed my box-shadow, so I would prefer a solution without it.

Comment: So what is it you want to do? If you don't want `min-width` to kick in, remove it. The browser can't keep on fitting `div`s next to each other that don't fit on a shrinking screen. Also, don't consider using tables for this, that's a 1999 approach.

Comment: Exactly what Arman H said. What you could consider doing is adding a min-width to div2 so that it has something to kick in if you were ever to shrink the first to 130px just so it never has to reach the situation where it needs to go under div1 because the text inside cannot fit.

Comment: @Arman H: I want the min-width because I don't want the left div to be too small when the window is resized.  However, I want the right div to keep shrinking in place.  With my current code, it shrinks but not fast enough because the left div isn't shrinking anymore, so it is pushed down.

Comment: @aug: I want the right div to keep shrinking no matter how small the window becomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also contain floats with `overflow:hidden`:

```
#div2{
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

The DIV will fill up the remaining space (http://jsfiddle.net/MAjwt/)

Comment: Thank you so much!!  The solution is so simple and elegant!  One question though, would setting "overflow: auto" be any different than "overflow: hidden"?

Comment: It depends on what content does the div have. `auto` also prevents it to jump below, but you may get to see scrollbars if the text inside does not fit. Example- http://jsfiddle.net/sMJ32/ (adding `word-wrap: break-word` could fix this though)

Answer (score 2):

Your thinking of using tables is somewhat on the right track, as table elements do actually have many properties that make them capable of such a thing, but as people are pointing out in the comments, it's no longer a valid approach to use table elements for the purposes of layout for non-tabular data.

This is why CSS implemented a set of style rules built to reflect those unique properties. You can set a container around two elements with the style `display: table;`, and then give it's children the style `display: table-cell;`

Setting the width for the right side div to 100% will ensure it always fills as much space as is available to it.

But, since table cells can't break to a new row when the content exceeds the width of the table, it will automatically adjust to fit. So when another div (the left one) has a specific min-width, the div on the right is given less space in order to keep the cells contained.

Here's an example using your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5rjL/

CSS table display properties give you all the benefits of these unique elements, but without the semantic issues. They are great for complex layouts where other style display types fall short.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I couldn't quite get your solution to work with my code despite the jsfiddle.  Your answer is much appreciated though!